# Create claims for a Blazor WebAssembly project

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I use the default Blazor WebAssembly template to create a project using the “individual user accounts option” and I try to create a custom claim when the user login and access it from the Blazor client side but I have not managed to make it work.

I know that I will have to create a custom authentication state provider for the Blazor client project but after several hours trying to make it work, I have not found a solution to my problem.

Can someone give me some tips of how to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization()
    .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

`CustomAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs`

```
public class CustomAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory
    : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>
{
    private const string Planet = "planet";

    public CustomAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor)
        : base(accessor) { }

    public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(
        RemoteUserAccount account,
        RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;
            var claims = identity.Claims.Where(a => a.Type == Planet);
            if (!claims.Any())
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Planet, "mars"));
            }
        }
        return user;

    }

}
```

`ClaimDisplay.razor`

```
@using System.Linq
@using System.Threading.Tasks
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

@ClaimType: @Claim
@code {
    [Inject]
    AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string ClaimType { get; set; }

    public string Claim { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userClaims = user.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type.Equals(ClaimType));
            Claims = userClaims.Any() ? userClaims.Select(claim => claim.Value).Aggregate(AddClaims) : "";
        }
    }

    private static string AddClaims(string left, string right) => left + ", " + right;
}
```

**usage**:

```
<ClaimDisplay ClaimType="planet" />
```

Working [demo](https://github.com/BrianLParker/RoleBaseAuth)

Comment: Thank you very much Brian. I was following a completely wrong approach. You helped me a lot with your example. Thank you again.

Comment: One more question if you know. Can this function be implemented by the server? Can we define claims on the server during login?